# Is Parse an adequate solution here?

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I'm contemplating to use Parse as a platform for my app, as I'm trying to avoid creating and managing the cloud infrastructure myself.

For the sake of simplicity let's say that my app will hook into an Exchange Server and will need to leverage some hosted Machine Learning service to categorize my e-mail and report on insights found.

I'm assuming that Parse would store my core data, while the hosted ML will store the "Big Data" associated with processing for insights.

I'm also expecting my app to receive push notifications generated by the hosted ML service.

Does this sound like a plausible way to go about it and leverage Parse,  or am I better off developing the backend myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think parse.com is the right place for you requirements, because they have everything you need like storage of core data, push notifications, cloud module which can be integrated with `heroku`, social integration, user management functionalities.

They also have large set of client libraries for desktop and mobile apps (node,java,.net etc...) also they have libraries of embedded devices.

The biggest advantage is that everything is setup, and you are focused on software development not on infrastructure things. This is my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay! A follow up question: is there a way to interact with Machine Learning services (AWS ML, Big ML etc) from inside Parse? I didn't find any documentation on this, but would think it is achieved via  the Cloud Code module, basically me writing custom code and hosting it on Parse.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS ML and Big ML but you answered yourself of your questions. Cloud code is your own custom code, which can be hosted on parse.com.  They provide scheduled jobs, async execution etc. If AWS ML and BIG ML apis support REST services it will be very easy to interact with them from parse.

Comment: no problem. upvote or marked as answered are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with the above stack and so far was really impressed. Seems like a viable path forward. The Cloud Code capability of Parse is very solid,  and easy to work with.  If you want to run services outside of Parse code this us also possible : just issue REST calls.